# AWS Lambda: encoding problem when creating and downloading EXCEL file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, openpyxl

I’m creating a microservice to dynamically generate EXCEL files and download them.

I have an AWS Api Gateway and a Python 3.8 Lambda function. To create the EXCEL I use the Openpyxl package.

The file is generated fine but when I download it I seem to get some encoding problem I can’t figure out.

**The Lambda**

Here I summarize the function, highlighting the end, where I save the file to a buffer and return it.

```
wb = I create my Workbook correctly

buffer = io.BytesIO()
wb.save(buffer)
    
excel_final = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
         
response = excel_final

return response
```

When testing the Lambda output, I see this response, that look Unicode:

> “PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\u0000\b\u0000}t\u008dT\u………….”

**Api Gateway**

The Integration Response is set to Passthrough and the Method Response to application/xml. Tried with different setups but couldn’t get it working.

When I test the API method, I also get the data in the following format, I think it’s utf-8 decoded:

> “PK�u�TAMb��docProps/app.xmlM�= 1D��q��A�Bb@�R��{/�dC�B~�9��noF�
> g*�-�T��"���N]�n�h�cy;�Ό�HI`���   ���M��F�r�xN��pe'å!
> �rmީ�5�&����;i^PK�u�T�z���docProps/core.xml���N�0�_e�u�V=DY.C�@Bb�[�x[E�F�Q��'-[������V����

**Javascript**

In my `request.onload` I get the bytes response and turn it into a Blob for download.

```
let blob = this.response;
let final_blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/xml'})
```

The file is downloaded but recognized as corrupt. Can’t open it.

**Tests**

I tried different Content-Types, coding/encoding in Lambda or Javascript, but never got it working.

Any clues welcome!

Comment: Is API Gateway Binary Support set up correctly? This article is a good practical example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Comment: Also, we often do file downloads with Lambda at my company. Whenever we do, we save the file in S3 and return a S3 presigned url to the Web App. This is a nice pattern that avoids all of the API Gateway headache.

Comment: @tankthinks Read the article and other similar, It looks it has more to do with byte input rather than output. When you edit "Integration Request" what you are affecting is the input before Lambda, right?

Comment: @tankthinks I thought about saving to S3, but seems a too expensive walkaround solution for something that must be only a problem of encoding. I made another similar service to create/download PDFs with no problem.

Comment: expensive how? In $$? I think a retention policy on the bucket will help avoid most costs. API Gateway costs will be the biggest part of this stack. I can help estimate/optimize with cost if your interested. If by expensive, you mean performance, maybe ... this will add ~40-150ms.

Comment: but in any case, back to your problem. Yes: modifying the integration request changes the data you pass to Lambda. If you can edit that, you must not be using the Lambda Proxy Integration, have you tried that?

Comment: also, one note, you said that the "Method Response to application/xml", that doesn't seem right for this response content.

Comment: @tankthinks My problem is in the output of Lambda, not in the input. Already implementing the S3 option. There must be a way to do what I want, but very little documentation including Openpyxl. Thanks for the info. We'll come back further on if I find the solution.

Comment: @tankthinks Have a look at my answer. I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it working and I’m able to download PDF, EXCEL or ZIP files directly from Lambda, without actually storing the file in a S3 bucket.

**Lambda**

Communication between Lambdas and Api Gateway requires base64 encoding, so in the Lambda I just return the bare base64 encoded binary.

```
wb = I create my Workbook correctly 
buffer = io.BytesIO() 
wb.save(buffer) 
excel_final = buffer.getvalue() 
buffer.close()

return base64.b64encode(excel_final)
```

**Api Gateway - Settings**

First go to Settings of your API and add `application/ms-excel` at 'Binary Media Types'.

**Api Gateway - Method Response**

Add `Content-Type` header at ‘Response Headers for 200’.

Add `application/ms-excel` response model at ‘Response Body for 200’

**Api Gateway - Integration Response**

Set `Content handling` to `Convert to binary (if needed)`.

Set `Content-Type` value to `application/ms-excel` at ‘Header Mappings’.

**Frontend**

Now you’ll receive a binary file as your response.
Just generate the blob and download as you prefer.

```
let blob = this.response;
let final_blob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/xml'});

// In my case I generate a link and click it
```

**Conclusion**

In my rookiness, I was messing around with the config having always something wrong in the chain. In my defense I must say documentation didn’t help too much.

Once I got it working It doesn’t seem like much of a hassle and works like a charm with any kind of binary file.

With the S3 approach you are required needlessly to store a file, make another request to download it and finally delete it from the bucket.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This approach looks good even I have a similar usecase but when I try to open the excel file in my case it gives me "can't open file the extension and format don't match" any idea what might be causing it ? I made the changes to API gateway config as recommended in your answer and encoded my response to base64

Comment: Hi @Himanshu I guess your are not generating the workbook correctly, before using the pipeline to deliver the file.